# PL/SQL inserting a new record exception handling

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an assignment in Oracle PL/SQL. I have to count the maximum number of employees working under a manager, and if this manager has more than 7 employees working under him I must raise an exception, which gives the message:

> ('Manager ||manager_name||' has maximium number of employees working under him'.)

Otherwise I must insert a new employee and give the message:

> ('It was inserted a new employee for the manager ||manager_name).

I have written the code, but I know something is wrong.

```
create table temp_emp as select * from employees;

select * from temp_emp;


create or replace procedure insert_emp(mngrId IN temp_emp.manager_id%type)
IS

    ex_hugemp EXCEPTION;
    emp_counter NUMBER;
    fname temp_emp.first_name%type;

BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO emp_counter
      FROM temp_emp 
      WHERE temp_emp.manager_id=mngrId;

    IF emp_counter > 7 THEN
        RAISE ex_hugemp;
    ELSE

      INSERT INTO temp_emp(EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PHONE_NUMBER
                          ,HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, SALARY, COMMISSION_PCT
                          ,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID)
        VALUES(LENGTH(EMPLOYEE_ID)+1, 'KAY', 'HORSTMAN', NULL, NULL
              ,'28-MAY-2013', 'IT_PROG', 24000, NULL, 103, 60);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('It was inserted a new employee for the manager   '||fname);

    END IF;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN ex_hugemp THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Manager '||fname||'  has maximium number of employees    working under him.');

END;
/
```

Comment: You say you know something is going wrong. How do you do? Do you get an error message? If you want us to help you need to give us a clue.

Comment: @APC, yes the compiler log gives me errors : Error(13,2): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored   and  Error(14,24): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Comment: PL/SQL: ORA-00984: because you use EMPLOYEE_ID in Values clause. Not allowed

Comment: 1) If you ask a question, it should be a question and not a tag cloud. 2) Please try to improve your spelling. Although high level English is not expected here, but you can get much better acceptance if you follow this [six simple spelling rules](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/my-question-was-downvoted-closed-because-it-was-full-of-grammatical-mistakes-wh/291370#291370).

Comment: @peterh look I did not ask this question to show me how to spell or something.  I've been trying for a week to solve this assignment and now I am searching for help so please give spelling lectures somewhere else. If I've done "spelling mistakes" then why are some others trying to help me to solve the question? Thanks for the suggestion anyway :-)

Comment: @IKEIN You are asking help from others, and you don't even try to write as literate people do... I am sorry, but it is laughing. If you ask others to help you, don't make their task harder.

Comment: @peterh I did not sign on here to discuss this things sir. there are people who write "worse" than that so I think this is pretty clear. I'm sorry if you don't understand the question.

Comment: I am new here. I signed on today and I don't know how to format text. But thank you @peterh

Comment: Text is organized into sentences, and the sentences start with an uppercase letter, and they end with a "." . If you need to learn this here, because you didn't learn that in the elementary school, then maybe not this SQL question is the main problem in your life. Read the link, these spelling rules are really important.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your variable fname is empty. Fill it:

```
SELECT first_name
  INTO fname
  FROM temp_emp
 WHERE employee_id = mngrid;
```

Use for the insert the same mngrid. Why is 103?

What is

```
LENGTH(EMPLOYEE_ID)+1
```

First: this will convert employee_id in string, get the length from the string and add 1. Do you really want this?. And second: you cannot use column name in values(). Create sequence (change 1 with your value to start):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TEMP_EMP_SEQ START WITH 1;
```

and than use it in your procedure

```
temp_emp_seq.nextval
```

.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_emp (mngrid IN temp_emp.manager_id%TYPE) IS
   ex_hugemp   EXCEPTION;
   emp_counter NUMBER;
   fname       temp_emp.first_name%TYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT first_name
     INTO fname
     FROM temp_emp
    WHERE employee_id = mngrid;

   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO emp_counter
     FROM temp_emp
    WHERE temp_emp.manager_id = mngrid;

   IF emp_counter > 7 THEN
      RAISE ex_hugemp;
   ELSE
      INSERT INTO temp_emp (employee_id, first_name, last_name, email, phone_number, hire_date, job_id, SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID)
         VALUES( temp_emp_seq.nextval,'KAY','HORSTMAN',NULL,NULL,TO_DATE('28-05-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),'IT_PROG',24000,NULL,mngrid,10);

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('It was inserted a new employee for the manager   ' || fname);
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN ex_hugemp THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Manager ' || fname || '  has maximium number of employees    working under him.');
END;
/
```

Comment: I tried to edit the pieces you told me. Yes you are right, and I used a sequence this time, but If I execute the procedure it also gives me errors :(

Comment: @IKEIN Tell us what for errors you get and show us the code.

Comment: Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT_EMP" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ; immediate
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "INSERT_EMP" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Comment: it does not give me the messages I want...It is not added any new employee

Comment: I did this and I just wanted a more proffessional help because I didn't know who else to ask, but thank you very much for the help :-)